# How to get hourly diff from cumulative daily data R

Tags: r

I have data in two columns:

```
DateTime    Profit
20130319T01  5
20130319T02  135
20130319T03  245
20130320T01  10
20130320T02  115
```

and I want to create a column that has the diff for each hour BUT the problem is that Profit resets to zero each day. I want to get the following:

```
DateTime     Diff
20130319T01  5
20130319T02  130
20130319T03  110
20130320T01  10
20130320T02  105
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the format of your DateTime character vector is always `"YYYYMMDD"` then you can use the `ddply` function from `plyr` to get what you want:

```
require(plyr)
df$Date <- substr( df$DateTime , 1 , 8 )
ddply( df ,  .(Date)  , summarise , Diff = diff(c(0,Profit)) )
#     Date Diff
#1 20130319    5
#2 20130319  130
#3 20130319  110
#4 20130320   10
#5 20130320  105
```

---

Another way using base's `ave`:

```
within(df, { Profit_diff <- ave(Profit, list(gsub("T.*$", "", DateTime)), 
             FUN=function(x) c(x[1], diff(x)))})

#      DateTime Profit Profit_diff
# 1 20130319T01      5           5
# 2 20130319T02    135         130
# 3 20130319T03    245         110
# 4 20130320T01     10          10
# 5 20130320T02    115         105
```

Comment: Any idea why I get this error:
> require(plyr)
Loading required package: plyr
Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘plyr’

Comment: Beacuse you don't have `plyr` installed? Try `install.packages("plyr")` first, and then don't forget to load it with `require(plyr)`

Comment: That did it! Thanks this seems to be a very fast solution.